# how we can give condtions for auto CASE creation while incoming mail comes in suiteCRM

Tags: suitecrm

how can we give conditions while creating the auto  case and when incoming mail comes,
may I know the auto case creation CODE when any incoming mail comes in suiteCRM  ?

I need to write some conditions before creating the case.

Could anyone help me where I need to write the condition(which FILE) and how can I write it?

My condition is,

If that incoming mail is `[FW:]` or `[RE]` case should not create

someone help on it please?

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Which version of SuiteCRM?

Comment: @Star  thanks for your response ,I am using 7.11.15 Version

Comment: @Star can you help on it please ,I was struggling so many days on this issue ?

Comment: Don't worry. Will share the answer today.

Comment: @Star thanks for your response ,that is soo help for me .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

SuiteCRM uses a `Check Inbound Mailboxes` scheduler for importing email from configured inbound email. The function for this scheduler is `pollMonitoredInboxesAOP` and it is written in `modules/Schedulers/_AddJobsHere.php`.

If you further dig into `pollMonitoredInboxesAOP` function, you will find out that it is calling `returnImportedEmail` of `modules/InboundEmail/InboundEmail.php`. In line 5337, it is using `subject` like following:

```
$email->name = $this->handleMimeHeaderDecode($header->subject);
```

Hopefully, above details will help you to build your logic.